# item will not be added to shopping list

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am very beginner in ReactJS and I want to do this small task.
With ReactJs, Hook, Functions and not with Class.

A Simple Shopping list:

- a card with an unordered list
- next to each list item a button to delete
- an input field to add more items
- a button that contains the add function

That is what I so far did. but it does not work.
when I on add-btn clicked, items does not add to list.

App Component:

```
import './App.css';
import ShowList from "./componenten/ShowList";
import AddList from "./componenten/AddList";
import React, {useState} from "react";


function App() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([
        {itemName: 'Test Item 01'},
    ]);

  return (
    <div className="App">

        <AddList setItema={[items,setItems]}/>
        <ShowList items={items}/>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

AddList Component:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Button, Input} from "antd";


export default function AddList ({items, setItems}){

    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

    const handleAddButtonClick = () => {
        const newItem ={
            itemName: inputValue,
        };

        const newItems = [...items,newItem];

        setItems(newItems);
        setInputValue('');
    }

    return(
        <>

        <Input value={inputValue} onChange={(event) =>
            setInputValue(event.target.value)}
               className='addItemInput'
               placeholder="Artikel hinzufügen" />

        <Button
            type="primary"
            className='btn'
            onClick={() => handleAddButtonClick()}
        >Hinzufügen</Button>

        </>

);
}
```

ShowList Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button} from "antd";

export default function ShowList ({items}){
    return(
        <div className='itemList'>
            {items.map((item) => (
                <ul className='itemContainer'>

                    <li className='item-name'>
                        {item.itemName}
                    </li>

                    <div className='delete-btn'>
                        <Button type="primary" danger ghost>
                            Delete
                        </Button>
                    </div>

                </ul>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo and a structural mistake here:

```
<AddList setItema={[items,setItems]}/>
```

The typo, clearly, is that `setItema` is not the same as `setItems`.  But the structural mistake is that this is not how one would commonly pass multiple props to a component.  Because this only passes *one* prop to the component, and that prop is an array.  But the component is expecting multiple props:

```
export default function AddList ({items, setItems})
```

Pass the props separately:

```
<AddList items={items} setItems={setItems} />
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing is the way you are passing props to AddList

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
```

the first variable is your state, and the second one a function that updates that state.

You can pass those variables as props to

```
<AddList items={items} setItems={setItems} />
```